# Encrypt External HardDrive that contain Data

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption

Is there an easy way to encrypt my 2To hard-drive that is completely full, without having to buy another one format / encrypt the drive, and then finally transfer all the data over ?

Comment: Which OS are you using? They all use diffent kinds of full disk encryption. (Linux=LUKS, FreeBSD=geli, OpenBSD=softraid ...)

Answer (score 0):

If the disk is *completely* full, no. There's an overhead of at least a few megabytes for an encrypted volume.

With full-disk encryption (dmcrypt), encrypting an existing volume isn't supported out of the box. However [luksipc](http://www.johannes-bauer.com/linux/luksipc/) (LUKS In-Place-Conversion Tool) automates the process of creating a small encrypted volume, copying a little data onto it, growing the volume (overwriting the plaintext that was just copied), and so on until the whole volume is encrypted. I'll quote its disclaimer:

> Before you attempt to do anything with the device, be warned: You may
>   lose some of your data, even all of it (for example if you put the
>   LUKS device key in `/dev/shm` and reboot your system before you add
>   another key to the keyring). Power failures are also bad (since you
>   will not have a resume file in that case). Furthermore, luksipc may
>   have bugs that wreak havoc on your data. Also keep in mind that
>   luksipc relies completely on a perfect disk. If your disk has
>   read-problems, it likely will abort somewhere within the middle of the
>   process (most likely also without creating a resume file). If your
>   disk is faulty, get a new one instead of trying to crypt it. And, most
>   importantly: **Always have a backup**. Now, let's be honest here: You
>   probably don't have a backup. If you had the disk space, you wouldn't
>   have the need to convert data in-place. Or maybe you have one and it's
>   really old. Or the data is not really that important. In any case,
>   please please please do not assume that everything will run smoothly.
>   It may not. You have been warned. I will not be held responsible for
>   any of your actions.
>
> That said let me point out that I trusted my software (after thourough
>   testing) enough to let it convert a 1 TB partition without having a
>   backup. This worked nicely. However, your milage may vary.